# Dropzone - Replace filename with link after upload is complete?

Tags: dropzone.js

I've integrated dropzone and it's working fine with the files getting uploaded etc. What I'd like to do is hide the progress bar once the upload is successful and replace the filename with a link to the actual upload file automatically. This would happen automatically as each file finished uploading...

Looking at the documentation, I know I should use

```
            this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                if (response.success == 'true') {
                  // hide progress bar '.dz-progress'
                  // replace .data-dz-name with url from response
                }
            });
```

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to get access to that specific html element to replace/hide etc.

**Edit:** I was able to use css classes from the original dropzone.css to hide/transition the progress bar. Now just need to find a way to replace the filename with an 'a' tag.

Answer (score 1):

#### For Dropzone **5.x** and above

The correct way to update the thumbnail is by modifying the **Preview Template** in the success callback as follows:

```
this.on("success", function(file, response) {
    // modify the preview template
    file.previewTemplate.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.filePath));
});
```

**[Reference tutorial](http://digitalfortress.tech/js/js-file-upload-dropzone-symfony/)** for Dropzone along with server side handling

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dz-progress').hide();
```

or

```
$(".dz-progress").remove();
```

and to replace `.data-dz-name`

```
$('.data-dz-name').html(url from response);
```

Comment: This will set *all* instances of '.data-dz-name' and not just the one for that specific "file" instance. If I drop 30 files at the same time, then I want each one to be updated with its corresponding url...